# Set prop value from a plugin vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have installed this plugin: https://github.com/eddiemf/vue-affix/blob/master/src/affix.vue

I need edit prop: enabled from a this plugin in app.js.

I have this code in my app:

```
import Affix from 'vue-affix';

var affix = Vue.use(Affix);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data() {

    },

    mounted() {
       this.usePushStateForTabs('.spark-tabs');
       this.calcStickyWidth();
       this.$nextTick(function() {
          window.addEventListener('resize', this.calcStickyWidth);
       })
    },

    methods: {
     calcStickyWidth() {
        let width = $('.vue-affix').parent().width();

        $('.vue-affix').css('width', width + 'px');

        if(! this.isMobile) { affix.enabled = false; }
     },

     isMobile() {
        return $(window).width() > 768 ? true : false
     },
    }
 });
```

I need set enabled prop to `false`. But my solution is not working. I get undefined. Help please fix it.